# ajax and javascript issue - functions not firing or firing mutiple times

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have put together an ajax powered chat/social network with jquery, PHP - but am having problems with the javascript.

I have a js file in the main page which loads the php in a div container, the js file is underneath the div. But only one function for posting a msg seems to work but the others do not.

I have tried including the js file with the dynamically loaded php at the end of the ajax load the functions work fine but am getting mutiple entries of the same message/comment.

I am pretty sure its not the PHP as it seems to work fine with no ajax involvment. Is there a way to solve this?

this is the function that works fine:

```
$("#newmsgsend").click(function(){

    var username = $("#loggedin").html();
    var userid = $("#loggedin").attr("uid");
    var message = $("#newmsgcontent").val();

    if(message == "" || message == "Enter Message..."){
        return false;
    }

    var datastring = 'username=' + username + '&message=' + message + '&uid=' + userid;

    //alert(datastring);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "uploadmsgimage.php",
        data: datastring,

        success: function(data){
            document.newmessage.newmsgcontent.value="";

            //need to clear browse value too
            $('.msgimage').hide('slow');
            $('#addmsgimage').show('slow');
            $(".usermsg").html(data);
            $("#control").replaceWith('<input type="file" name="file"/>');
            $(".msgimage").remove();
        }
    });
});
```

And this is one of them that does not work:

```
//like btn
$(".like").click(function(){

    var postid = $(this).attr("pid");

    var datastring = 'likeid=' + postid;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "addlike.php",
        data: datastring,
        success: function(data){
            $(".usermsg").html(data); 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Use Firefox + Firebug, open the NET tab and watch what your request is doing.

Comment: It may be due to Bubbling effect of Jquery. Try stopimmediatepropagation

Comment: Can you include some HTML from the browser so that we can see what the DOM looks like when the jQuery activates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your post, I'm guessing that each message has a "Like" button, but you have 1 main submit button. When messages load dynamically, you have to assign the .like to each one when they come in, otherwise it will only be assigned to the existing messages.

The problem, from what I gather (and this is a guess) would probably be fixed using live so jQuery will automatically assign the click function to all messages including dynamically loaded messages; so instead of:

```
$(".like").click(function(){
```

Try this:

```
$(".like").live('click', function(){
```

If that doesn't solve the problem, then I'm probably not understanding what it is.

Comment: note (source: [jQuery live() doc](http://api.jquery.com/live/)):  
"As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()."

Comment: great .live who knew! Next i have to figure how to get comments section working!

Comment: @CronosS, Thanks! Looks like I have some testing to do to change my live events over to http://api.jquery.com/on/
I haven't looked at the live documentation since jQuery 1.3.2.
Looks like "on" events are designed to watch a certain area instead of the entire document, so that should be a lot more efficient.